# In Laravel I want a page history not be stored in browser history?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.8, back, forward

Currently, I am working on a **Quiz based project** using `Laravel 5.8`. But there is a situation where a user needs to gave certain input to participate in a quiz. After that, they will submit the quiz and then the answer to that quiz will appear. But there is a problem when a user presses, the back button then the quiz participate page comes again. Now they can again give the same quiz again. But what I want is if a user presses the back button it will go to the quiz creation page, not the quiz participation page. At the same time if the user presses the forward button from the quiz creation page it will go to the answer page, not on the quiz participation page.

Brief demonstration what I want:

```
`Quiz creation page`=> `Quiz participation Page (Can come after giving input in quiz creation page)`=>`Quiz Answer Page`
```

If a user press back and forward button it will cycle between the following two pages.

```
`Quiz creation page`=>`Quiz Answer Page`
```

**Quiz participation page** will not be in the browser history so this page will not come if a user press backward and forward button. So how can I achieve this?

`There is an interesting point if a user knows the **Quiz participation page** they can go to that page.`

Comment: You can't ask a browser to not remember a link. You can however expire a URL after certain action (passing test, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to track the user's progress if you want this to happen. You can't disable the user from saving history but you can redirect the current user's progress.

Create a table that tracks the user's progress, perhaps add finished_at to track if the quiz is finished so you can redirect the user immediately.

```php
use Auth;

$progress = QuizProgress::where('user_id', Auth::user()->getKey())
    ->where('quiz_id', 1)
    ->firstOrFail();

if ($progress->finished_at) {
    return redirect();
}

return redirect()->url('quiz/' . $progress->current_progress);
```